# Unity - namespaces not detecting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, visual-studio-2017

Despite my title, I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

I have been following along a tutorial Unity course and have encountered a problem after installing the latest version of Unity.

When I open Visual Studio 2017 in my tutorial project (and now /other/ Unity projects I have), I get the error/warning messages :

[Receive x 1]
The project  cannot be added to the solution because a project with the same project filename already exists in the solution.

[Receive x 3] * note the ‘.Editor’ immediately below
The project  cannot be added to the solution because a project with the same project filename already exists in the solution.

This happens every time I open VS2017 or am prompted to reload the solution (in which case I do reload the solution).

So, in my Swords & Shovels project /and other older projects/, Unity namespaces are not being DETECTED (in the sense they do not auto-complete) but MonoBehaviour functions(?) like Awake(), Start(), etc. still seem to work. These functions will not auto-complete in the IDE, but they will function (tested with an Awake() – can provide Unity.Console log proof if necessary).

But on the other hand, references don’t seem to be accepted by the inspector (NullReferenceException). I have tried “renewing” the reference object from the inspector, but it still does not work.

BRAND NEW PROJECTS (made just for this "assistance plea") behave almost the same way except that they also receive the first error/warning message x1, but they only receive the second error/warning message x2 (the ‘.Editor’ message). (In terms of the number of scripts that each project contains, my own personal project has probably 100+ (90% due to duplicates) scripts, whereas the point in which I'm at in this course's project has maybe 12~ (at the most? didn't count), and the brand new project is only tested with one script. I mention this in case script count has anything to do with the error messages.)

Additionally, brand new projects continue to detect namespaces despite the project being closed and reopened (and having my computer shut down and turned back on): syntax auto-completes, MonoBehaviour functions work as intended, and references from the inspector are detected.

Comment: This happened to me when I import a package to my project and some scripts have the same namespaces or script-titles, did you import some new package to your project?

Comment: I have imported assets but this problem still occurs in brand new projects with no imports. I'll try to look into this particular solution though, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found a post on github of a user encountering the same erorr.
Although I cannot *explain* the origin of my problem, the solution was to simply update VS2017. According to the post, the problem may have had something to do with 'asmdef' not being supported.

For clarity: my namespaces/other syntax now auto-complete/are "detected", I no longer encounter the error/warning messages upon opening/reloading VS2017, and as far as I can tell, my references work for the most part (I think it's an error on my part now, hahaha).

Thank you all for your time and help.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/AssetBundles-Browser/issues/66

(Sorry if the link breaks any rules, I can edit it out if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

> a project with the same project filename already exists in the solution.

Not sure, but maybe go to the directory, find the project file and rename it?

Comment: Tried renaming the project, the error/warning messages just display the new project filename instead. Thanks for your help though.